# Can't resolve symbol "FirstOrDefaultAsync" in .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a .Net Core Web API and in one of the files the FirstOrDefaultAsync() method just doesn't work although I'm using it in various files in the same project. I have all the necessary NuGet packages and namespaces. Other  EFCore methods such as SaveChangesAsync seem to work just as usual.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

...

public async Task<NoteDetailsVm> Handle(GetNoteBodyQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = await _dbContext.FirstOrDefaultAsync(note => note.Id == query.Id, cancellationToken);
    ...
}
```

The IDE just doesn't recognize the method. Though the namespace gets highlited when I type in the name of the method, nothing really happens.
In another file in the same project i have:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

...

public async Task<Unit> Handle(UpdateNoteCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = await _dbContext.Notes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(note =>
        note.Id == request.Id, cancellationToken);
    ...
}
```

and everything works perfectly.

How can I make the IDE recognize the method?

Comment: `_dbContext.Notes.FirstOrDefaultAsync` works, but `_dbContext.FirstOrDefaultAsync` doesn't. Can you see the difference there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to include a ef dbset name into db context code

```
  var entity = await _dbContext.Notes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(note => note.Id == query.Id, cancellationToken);

  //or
  var entity = await _dbContext.Set<Note>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(note => note.Id == query.Id, cancellationToken);
```